# Can 2 redis servers share the same snapshot dump file?

Tags: c#, .net, nosql, redis

Is it possible to have a Redis server running on two machines and each server specifies in the config file the same snapshot dump file name and directory, with the directory and file obviously being shared between both machines?

RavenDB seems to work fine with that, I can setup the whole server file directory on a Dropbox folder on my machine and do the same on the other machine with the two drop boxes syncing while the RavenDb servers read and write data from/to the database that is stored within the drop box folder.

I understand both DBs' concepts are very different, I just use the RavenDB experience as example to explain what I try to accomplish. Please note this is just for developing purposes not to run in production.

I am running Redis in Version 2.4.5 as a Windows service and use BookSleeve as client within C# .Net 4.5

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most certainly not.  This would be a sure way to ensure a corrupt file.

You might want to watch progress on Redis Cluster (http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec), currently at the specification stage.

Comment: It does not necessarily corrupt files unless the server overwrites the whole file and includes server specific information (which it should not anyway). The example I mentioned (RavenDB) does not in any way corrupt any files. So, maybe a follow up question would be, are you aware whether I can turn off auto snapshot and still commit added keys through code which in turn are saved in the snapshot file? I know that both servers never add keys at the same time. (I use one server instance on my laptop for outside work, and another server instance runs on my home machine.

Comment: I you don't run the servers at the same time, this could fly, but you are likely to lose data if both run at the same time.

Comment: They do run at the same time but as long as snap shotting is shut off in the config file they would never touch the dump file correct? So my question is whether I can force a dump through code or only through the server settings within the config file?

Comment: If you issue `SHUTDOWN SAVE`, it will force a save point to be generated before Redis shuts down.  This should ensure you have the latest data on disk.

Comment: THank you, but there is no command to issue a data dump to file during runtime?

Comment: I don't think so, but you can configure the persistence using AOF/fsync at every query, which is slower, but safest because the disk image should always have the latest. If you combine with `appendonly yes`, you should be fairly safe.

Comment: Thanks, I will reflect and play with your suggestions. Will revert back.

Comment: The command bgsave will, save to disk. However, as I said the server doesn't read from the file except at startup. Thus you can't achieve what you describe through syncing the dump file.  Redis is an in memory data store which can persist to disk, not a file based db.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am well aware of the underlying structure of Redis but was hoping for a function where redis would be able to sync the dump file at specified intervals with only syncing changes , not the entire file. I think this is why my approach does not work with Redis but Raven. But then Raven is not an inmemory db.

Answer (score 0):

The only time you would use the dump file on a system which does not have persistence enabled is on boot time. However, if persistence is disabled it doesn't read from the dump file.

Even without server specific data on the dump file the possibility for corruption comes at any and every point when both services write to the file. You could set the persistence settings to only save if there have been, say, 59 million changes in 60 seconds. This could allow you to read the file on load but not save to it. You would then need to use

`redis config set save ""`

To disable saving in both but be able to save when you want, you would do the above and issue a by save command.

I also have to advise against doing this over a shared file system, which is what you'll need to do this with multiple machines accessing the same file. In your case you are talking about Dropbox as your shared file system, but this is likely to kill performance if you are persisting to disk.

But ultimately, I'd have to ask why you think you need this?

If you are using one for read only, then use a slave or two and do reads on the slaves. This way you don't have to worry about multiple instances corrupting a persistence file. This avoid the need for shared storage as you have two nodes running each with a copy of the data. This provides redundancy and you can relatively easily work a master/slave failover setup.

Ultimately, if you are just using it to develop something against, I don't see the need for such a setup. Just store configuration where you can download it (Dropbox, github, etc) and develop away. It isn't difficult, and certainly less complicated, to simply copy your dump file to Dropbox or anywhere else you need it than to do what you describe.

Comment: thanks for your input, why I need this? I am in the developing process and frequently add some data for testing purposes to the database on either machine. I do not want to have to kill the server each time, having to copy over the dump file, restart the server just so that I have access to data from either machine regardless on which firm the key/value was added. Also, please note that my using Dropbox does not mean that the key/value is initially saved in the cloud. Its just saved on the local drive and drop box then syncs it with the cloud account.

Comment: As I said, copying over the dump file in any way does,not means the second instance gets the data. It just means you have a copy of the data in a place where if the second instance is configured to use the dump file it will overwrite it whenever it shuts down, and there is no way around that. What you are describing is needing a slave where the data changes are replicated to.  Use the built in replication instead of trying to do it in a way that won't work and you'll be much happier. If you truly need multi master for development, you are using the wrong data store.

Comment: Thats for pointing out the correct to-be-used terminology. I will try to find out more. In the meantime I simply make sure each server instance runs only when the other does not and after shutting down and syncing the file the other instance uses the updated dump file to startup properly. It works as expected. Again this is just in order to play around developing stuff while being away from my main machine with my laptop.